# Compiling an Ember template with specified values

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I need to get a template from `Ember.TEMPLATES`, compile it with a specified object and get its raw HTML value.

`Ember.TEMPLATES` content (generated using `gruntjs`) returns a function and seems to be already passed through `Handlebars.template()` function so for example I would have this:

```
Ember.TEMPLATES["test"] = Ember.Handlebars.template(function anonymous(Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
this.compilerInfo = [4,'>= 1.0.0'];
helpers = this.merge(helpers, Ember.Handlebars.helpers); data = data || {};
  var buffer = '', hashTypes, hashContexts, escapeExpression=this.escapeExpression;


  data.buffer.push("<strong>hello world ");
  hashTypes = {};
  hashContexts = {};
  data.buffer.push(escapeExpression(helpers._triageMustache.call(depth0, "test", {hash:{},contexts:[depth0],types:["ID"],hashContexts:hashContexts,hashTypes:hashTypes,data:data})));
  data.buffer.push("</strong>\n");
  return buffer;

});
```

and would like to compile that template with new values from a JSON object.

I tried something like that based on what I've seen in Ember code:

```
var test = Ember.TEMPLATES['test'];
var compiled = test({ test: 'value' });
```

I thought it might work but it doesn't actually.

Basically I'd like to do like with standard handlebars :

```
Handlebars.compile('<strong>{{hello}}</strong>', { hello: 'world' });
```

Is there any way to compile a template with specified values, and get the HTML result using Emberjs?

Comment: What you have on Ember.TEMPLATES["test"] it's a `pre-compiled` template. Could you get the source and compile that one as you have in your last example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ember do [some modifications in handlebars compiler](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/3054e23a9a94e309e9236d9288ef7080ec617daf/packages/ember-handlebars-compiler/lib/main.js) to enable the use of computed properties, make templates update when model changes etc.

If you see the [view render method](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L1209), it does more than `template(context)`, it use the context and some private custom data. So `Handlebars.compile` is diferent of `Ember.Handlebars.compile` and I think that compiled templates from Ember.Handlebars.compile, is not intended to be used outside of a `Ember.View`.

Marking script types with `text/x-raw-handlebars`, instead of `text/x-handlebars` make the template be compiled with `Handlebars.compile`.

The following sample will work, but without the ember features:

**Template**

```
<script type="text/x-raw-handlebars" data-template-name="custom-template">
    First name: {{firstName}} <br/>Last name: {{lastName}}
</script>
```

**Javascript**

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    ready: function() {
        var template = Ember.TEMPLATES['custom-template'];                    
        var html = template({ firstName: 'Tom', lastName: 'Dale' });
        $('body').append(html);
    }
});
```

You can see this sample here http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/MC8QB/

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, this makes so much more sense and now I have something to work with. Greatly appreciated and great response!

Comment: @MarcioJunior You did not answer the question. How will you read the compiled template which is a js file which will be included in your html. After reading passing an object to the template and get the html. The html should be placed inside a element in your html. You have given the difference between handlebars/Ember compilation and given a demo on reading a template which is in your html. I have asked the same question but did not get a convincing answer yet - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306224/handlebars-precompiled-templates-returns-undefined-value/23309047?noredirect=1#23309047