# Handlebars precompiled templates returns undefined value

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a template file test_temp.handlebars. Its content is,

```
<div>Hello {{name}}</div>
```

I compiled the template in my command line using the command,

```
handlebars test_temp.handlebars -f test_temp.js
```

The content of the test_temp.js file is,

```
(function() {
var template = Handlebars.template, templates = Handlebars.templates =Handlebars.templates || {};
templates['test_temp'] = template({"compiler":[5,">=2.0.0"],"main":function(depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
var helper, functionType="function", escapeExpression=this.escapeExpression;
return "<div>Hello "
+ escapeExpression(((helper = helpers.name || (depth0 && depth0.name)),(typeof helper === functionType ? helper.call(depth0, {"name":"name","hash":{},"data":data}) : helper)))
+ "</div>\n";
},"useData":true});
})();
```

Now i read my precompiled template in my html.

```
var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.templates['test_temp'];
var temp_html = compiledTemplate({ name: 'World' });
console.log(temp_html);  //undefined
```

Here the value returned to the temp_html is undefined.
Kindly let me know how to put this temp_html inside a div.

```
$("#tempdiv").html(temp_html);
```

When I update the temp_html inside the div, the error thrown is,

```
"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"
```

How to get the precompiled template value and insert it inside a div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22214119/432089

If you downloaded your handlebars from npm, you will get the 2.0 alpha build instead of the stable 1.3.0 build.  In other words, it's likely you have 2.0 alpha precompiled templates, but you are using the 1.3.0 runtime JS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your link and i got the answer and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8TMw4/

```
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div>Hello {{name}}</div>    
</script>

var source = $("#some-template").html(); 
var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 
console.log(template);
```

Comment: your code compiles the template in the browser. This will work. I need to compile my templates in back-end servers and read the js file as in my code which is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplished this task applying the following filters:

- Precompile templates in the backend (Use the build tools you prefer).
- Load the precompiled template to Ember.TEMPLATES['"+templateName+"'].
- You must follow ember naming convention in order Ember recognise where your route, view, or component templates are located. This is the job of the [Ember.DefaultResolver](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.DefaultResolver.html) and [ComponentLookup](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages_es6/ember-handlebars/lib/component_lookup.js). Specific naming convention could be defined if you implement your custom resolver and assigned it to the application instance.

You could look at this [demo example](https://github.com/ppcano/fast-rebuild-ember-app) whose build tools are either rake-pipeline or broccoli.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have precompiled my .hbs file using ember-precompile. Now how can I read the template and place inside a div. I read like,
    var compiledTemplate = Em.TEMPLATES['precompile'];compiledTemplate({ name: 'World' }); but Cannot read property 'push' of undefined error is thrown